# .remove() doesn't seem to work on my jQuery function

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate, infobubble

I'm trying to do an animate info speech bubble (I found the css of the bubble here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/), each time my mouse is over a link I'm creating a div infoBubble and when the mouse is out this div I'm deleting it using .remove(). But when I'm moving really fast my mouse from a link to an other one, .remove() doesn't seem to work on the first buuble.

my jQuery code is:

```
infoBubble = function(el){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').append('<div class="infoBubble"></div>');
        var bubble = $('.infoBubble:last');      
        var posTop = el.offset().top-el.height()-12;
        var posLeft = el.offset().left+el.width()/2-bubble.width()/2;
        bubble.css({ 'left':posLeft, 'top':posTop-10, 'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)', 'opacity':1 });
            bubble.html('eeeeeeeeee');
            bubble.stop().animate({ 'top':posTop },200); 
        },400);

}

infoBubbleStop = function(){
    var bubble = $('.infoBubble:last');
    bubble.stop().animate({ 'opacity':0 }, 200, 'linear', function(){ bubble.remove(); });
}

$(document).on('mouseover', 'a', function () {
    infoBubble($(this)); 
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    infoBubbleStop();
});
```

Here a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/YmKT4/

thanks a lot for helping...

Comment: Whenever the stop() function is invoked, the callback is not executed.

Comment: I tried without stop() but I have the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the timeout, try to modify a little your logic there like this for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YmKT4/6/

```
infoBubble = function (el) {
    $('body').append('<div class="infoBubble"></div>');
    var bubble = $('.infoBubble:last');
    var posTop = el.offset().top - el.height() - 12;
    var posLeft = el.offset().left + el.width() / 2 - bubble.width() / 2;
    bubble.hide().css({
        'left': posLeft,
        'top': posTop - 10,
        'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        'opacity': 1
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        bubble.show().html('eeeeeeeeee');
        bubble.animate({
            'top': posTop,
            'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
        }, 200);
    }, 400);

}
```

Comment: Just forget to remove it after debugging

Comment: oh ok, and also why did you prefer mouseenter over mouseover?

Comment: Still for debugging purpose, but in your case, you can use both. Just remember than mouseenter don't bubbles event while mouseover do by default.

Answer (score 0):

With the `jumpToEnd` parameter of [jQuery.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function, you should be able to run the complete function even if you stop the animation.

The problem will now be that you don't select the right `bubble`, you use the `:last` one, so it will always be the one you just created.

You should add your bubble for each link you have to mouseover :

http://jsfiddle.net/pboissonneault/YmKT4/4/

```
infoBubble = function(el){
            setTimeout(function(el) {
        el.append('<div class="infoBubble"></div>');
        var bubble = $('.infoBubble:last', el);      
        var posTop = el.offset().top-el.height()-12;
        var posLeft = el.offset().left+el.width()/2-bubble.width()/2;
        bubble.css({ 'left':posLeft, 'top':posTop-10, 'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'opacity':1 });
            bubble.html('eeeeeeeeee');
            bubble.stop().animate({ 'top':posTop, 'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)' },200); 
        }(el),400);

}

infoBubbleStop = function(el){
    var bubble = $('.infoBubble:last', el);
    bubble.stop(true, true).animate({ 'opacity':0 }, 200, 'linear', function(){ bubble.remove(); });
}

$(document).on('mouseover', 'a', function () {
    infoBubble($(this)); 
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    infoBubbleStop($(this));
});
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunatly when moving very fast the mouse from one like to an other the same issue comes

Answer (score 0):

change 400 to 4 ,in below line of code:

```
  infoBubble = function(el){
            setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').append('<div class="infoBubble"></div>');
        var bubble = $('.infoBubble:last');      
        var posTop = el.offset().top-el.height()-12;
        var posLeft = el.offset().left+el.width()/2-bubble.width()/2;
        bubble.css({ 'left':posLeft, 'top':posTop-10, 'background-color'rgba(0,   0, 0, 0)', 'opacity':1 });
            bubble.html('eeeeeeeeee');
            bubble.stop().animate({ 'top':posTop, 'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)' },200); 
        },4);

}

infoBubbleStop = function(){
    var bubble = $('.infoBubble:last');
    bubble.stop().animate({ 'opacity':0 }, 5, 'linear', function(){ bubble.remove(); });
}

$(document).on('mouseover', 'a', function () {
    infoBubble($(this)); 
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    infoBubbleStop();
});
```